# Send UserControl to view to display dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog

I'm working on my first foray into WPF and MVVM.  I have a need for a usercontrol that acts as a pseduo-dialog box - it 'dialogs' over the section of the application it is in (a tab), but allows the user to still switch to other areas of the application.

I'm trying to accomplish this via my `TabDialog` UserControl. Currently it just looks like:

```
<Grid
     Visibility="{Binding ShowAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        Background="black"
        Opacity=".5"
        />

    <Label Background="Red" 
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.Column="1"
           Content="{Binding ShowAvailable}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

where the `ShowAvailable` is a `Bool` on the parent's `DataContext`, and inherited in this control.

My problem now is, as i want to re-use this control for different 'dialog' views, I want to pass in which view it should display (will replace the `Label`).  How do I go about sending a usercontrol defined by the parent ViewModel into this view, and display it?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using DataTemplates and ContentControls.  Since the Content control isn't specifying a ContentTemplate, it determines which DataTemplate by the type of the viewmodel being bound to.  So to change which view is being used, just change the type of object being bound to.

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding ShowAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="LabelViewModel">
            <wpfApplication1:MyUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="NonLabelViewModel">
            <wpfApplication1:OtherUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.RowSpan="3"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    Background="black"
    Opacity=".5"
    />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModelObject}" />
</Grid>
```

LabelViewModel and NonLabelViewModel would be the ViewModels you would define, (and add to the parent view model that the grid is bound to, as a property named ViewModelObject )
and MyUserControl and OtherUserControl would be the User Controls to house the UI that should correspond for each of these ViewModel types.